# When to place a field description on the right?

Tags: mobile, grid, fields

In a two column grid of a mobile app, when is it better to place the "value" field on the left and the "description" field on the right and why?

Edit: language is Italian/English

Comment: I would only ever consider that if my app was displayed in a language that reads right-to-left. I can't imagine why you'd do that in an LTR language.

Comment: An example or mock up of what you are thinking will be helpful. Otherwise within general understanding, as mentioned in the previous comment it will be contradictory to do that with either Italian or English.

Answer (score 1):

A possible scenario I can think of is when the description is a measurement unit or currency unit.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/55371)

Comment: @Wanda  The question asked when, so suggested a possible scenario.

Comment: Your answer looks more like a comment, I wanted to add you should elaborate your answer a bit. These review auto-replies really miss the intention I wanted to get across :/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it right, I think the best approach is to have the text field on the left, always the mobile attention and actions are taken from the top left to bottom right. unless you don't have grids so the text field is better to occupy the whole width to be centered which is more usable and more comfort for the user.

Here I attached a screen to show what. I mean either place the description on the right side hand or place it below the text field.

Hope this can work!
[image]